# IDW error in ggplot in R

Tags: r, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted, gstat

I want to perform IDW interpolation and plot it with help of ggplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
kerpensample_df <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\49151\\Desktop\\kerpentest0909x.csv",
                            header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ",")
library(sf)
crs = st_crs("EPSG:32632")
head(kerpensample_df)
kerpensample_df_sf = st_as_sf(kerpensample_df, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = "OGC:CRS84")%>%
  st_transform(crs)
library(stars)
st_bbox(kerpensample_df_sf)%>%
  st_as_stars(dx = 10) %>%
  st_crop(kerpensample_df_sf) -> grd 
grd

library(gstat)

i = idw(Z~1, 
        as(kerpensample_df_sf, "Spatial"),
        grd,
)

ggplot(i, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill =Z)) +
```

Upon tyring my code, I get the following error message:

```
> ggplot(i, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill =Z))
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class stars.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

What does this error mean in essence? How can it be fixed and I need help with the ggplot function.

here is a sample of csv: https://ufile.io/liecksj6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class stars.

`i` is an object from the `stars` package, so `ggplot` doesn't know what to do with it, so it throws an error.

`i` is a stars object because `grd` is a stars object. Make `grd` an `sf` object and you'll get something back that's an `sf` object and `ggplot` can deal with those:

```
grd = st_as_sf(grd)
i = idw(Z~1, 
         as(kerpensample_df_sf, "Spatial"),
         grd,
 )
ggplot(i, aes(x = x, y = y, col =var1.pred)) + geom_point()
```